# How do I open this JSON data with Python?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, json, django

I'm sending the following in a POST request from ios to a django webserver:

```
NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef);
for (id rec in allContacts){
    ABMultiValueRef mvr = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)rec, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSArray *currentNums = (__bridge NSArray*) ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(mvr);
    [allPhoneNumbers addObjectsFromArray: currentNums];
}


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:allPhoneNumbers options:0 error:&error];

/*Set other request values...*/
//...
//...
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

Django runs on python, and I need to know how to access this JSON data..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for some python/django which decodes a JSON request?

Comment: That objective-C code appears to be irrelevant, since as John points out your question is in the title, which is easily google-able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django, the HTTP request body can be accessed as a string using the [body attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)  of the request object which can then be decoded using [json.loads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads)

eg.

```
import json

def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone_numbers = json.loads(request.body)
        for phone_number in phone_numbers:
            # do something here
```

Comment: This is great, but how do I parse the data inside of the body?

Comment: The `json.loads` will convert the json string into an appropriate python data structure (list or dict depending upon your json data) which you can use as per your needs. Sorry, I don't quite understand your question. Can you please specify what exactly you are trying to do on the django side?

Comment: All I'm passing to the django side is phone numbers. I'm not creating any type of hierarchy when I pass it... so I just need to access individual phone numbers.

Comment: In that case, `json.loads` will give you a normal python list that you may then iterate or do something else with it. See edited example.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. It seems I'm being passed a QueryDict.

Comment: What is being passed as a QueryDict? `request.body`? Can you log it somewhere and provide the output? Also check if you are setting the `application/json` header on the request sent to this service from objective-c side